# Does air have a maximun supported sound intensity?

Tags: acoustics

It's probably a stupid question, but I wonder what the limit of intensity is that sound can have in the air. I suppose that there's a limit, because very high pressures produced by the sound wave would maybe condense the air into liquid form, killing the sound wave, or maybe creating other bizarre effects.

Comment: Here is a site which gives you information about sound intensities and an answer to your question - undistorted sound. Any higher and you get a shock wave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure

Comment: I think that is a problem of definition. Is a shockwave still a kind of sound? Which thermodynamical disturbances should be labeled as a sound...? etc. There is pretty much evaluable border between linear and nonlinear acoustics. But when that ends and becomes some kind of general gas theory...

Answer (score 0):

Waves linear equations suppose that the amplitude is small compared to the "thickness". For volumes, thickness is the pressure.
The same that you wont call a splash a wave, you might don't call atmosphere moving apart and in a sound. :-)

Other phenomenon occurs at high intensity, as air heating, then changing locally the sound speed, etc, thus the "crack" sound of thunder that really sharpen along the first stages of the propagation.

Maybe your definition of sound could be "up to the non-linearities caused by the amplitude makes the sound content (i.e., the timbre) change as travelling. You should decide some threshold value, and would get your source intensity.